# Sorting table by every other row Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to sort my data with an extra row added for description type data that does NOT need to be sorted. I **cannot** hide/show this row since it's vital to the rest of the data making any sense.

Is there a way to do this with datatables?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Rank Col</th>
    <th>Power Col</th>
    <th>Money Col</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Image - Name goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Power Level</td>
    <td>Money</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Image - Name goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Power Level</td>
    <td>Money</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Image - Name goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Power Level</td>
    <td>Money</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Image - Name goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Power Level</td>
    <td>Money</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you mean each row has new "description type" row which should not sortable? (rows -> Image - Name goes here)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DataTables does support what you are trying to do, but not in the way that you have shown. You need to add [child elements](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()) to your rows. An easy way to do this in your example is to utilize a hidden column ([fiddle](http://live.datatables.net/movisoce/1/edit)):

**The HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank Col</th>
        <th>Power Col</th>
        <th>Money Col</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Power Level</td>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>Image - Name goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Power Level</td>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>Image - Name goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Power Level</td>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>Image - Name goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Power Level</td>
        <td>Money</td>
        <td>Image - Name goes here</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
function addChild ( data ) {

    // data contains all of your information,
    // e.g. data.rank, data.power_level, etc.

    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td colspan="3">' + data.description + '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
    "columns": [
      { "data": "rank" },
      { "data": "power_level" },
      { "data": "money" },
      { "data": "description", "visible": false }
    ]
});

// Add children
table.$('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var row = table.row( $(this) );
    row.child( addChild(row.data()) ).show();
});
```

In the code above, we hide the description column and attach a child table onto the parent table row.